# Can I subscribe to a Google Drive API event with no expiration time?

Tags: google-drive-api, webhooks

I would like to subscribe to a google drive file changes, without an expiration date. In the request I can either send the expiration or not (and the default is expiration in 1 hour).
Also, in the docs I see that the max expiration is 1 week.
Isn't there a way to watch for changes without expiration date? it seems weird...

From google drive api docs:
`Note: For the Google Drive API, the maximum expiration time is 86400 seconds (1 day) after the current time for File resources and 604800 seconds (1 week) for Changes. If you don’t set the expiration property in your request, the expiration time defaults to 3600 seconds after the current time.`

This is the request I'm sending (code from docs):
`
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files//watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "<my address>", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myFilesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your files channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration date and time.
}
```

`

and i would like to not have an expiration.